# Delete SQL for CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to delete from a document collection using SQL in CosmosDB?

I am looking for a Delete SQL similar to SELECT as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Families f 
WHERE f.id = "AndersenFamily"
```

I am looking for something:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Families f 
WHERE f.id = "AndersenFamily"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to delete from a document collection using SQL in
>   CosmosDB?

As of today it is not possible to do so. You will need to fetch the documents using `SELECT` query and then delete the documents individually using `DELETE Document` API (or appropriate delete method based on the SDK you're using).