# How to delete multiple documents in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

On Azure Cosmos DB portal, Data Explorer doesn't allow deletion of more than one document.

[image]

Is it possible to delete multiple documents in one go?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete multiple documents, but you can use stored procedure to delete documents in one partition.

Please refer to this Q&A set for information on that: [Azure CosmosDB: stored procedure delete documents based on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684344/azure-cosmosdb-stored-procedure-delete-documents-based-on-query)

Comment: It does delete items from single partition only.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't delete multiple documents in one go. Each document must be deleted separately.

One possible solution would be to write a stored procedure and pass the list of document ids that you want to delete. In that stored procedure, you can loop through that list and delete individual documents.

Comment: I knew that, I want to avoid coding if possible.

Comment: If you're looking for a tool to delete multiple documents, do take a look at Cerebrata Cerulean (https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean). It lets you select multiple documents and delete them in one go (behind the scenes, it deletes each document separately though). [Full Disclosure: My company is behind this tool]

Comment: Is it free to use?

Comment: Yes. It is a commercial software but we're offering a free 1 year subscription to all of our users so at least for an year you can use it for free.

Comment: is the software open source? My concern is that I have to provide the login credential of my work account.

Comment: @Pingpong This really isn't the place to have a discussion on how to get a product for free.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a small C# console application with the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` NuGet package installed. It might not be the fastest way of deleting documents, but it gets the job done. It assumes using `/id` as the partition key:

```csharp
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

// Fill in these
const string connectionString "";
const string databaseName = "";
const string containerName = "";
const string query = ""; // For example "SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE c.EnqueuedTimeUtc >= '2023-05-11T15:00';
const int batchCount = 80; // Some limit to prevent getting "429 Too Many Requests".

var client = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
var container = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
var iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyDoc>(query, requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions { MaxItemCount = batchCount });
while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    var deleteTasks = response.Select(doc => container.DeleteItemAsync<object>(doc.id, new PartitionKey(doc.id))).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(deleteTasks);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:T} - Deleted {deleteTasks.Count} documents");
}

Console.WriteLine("Done!");

class MyDoc
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: does anyone know if its cheaper to do bulk deletes in a stored proc. i suspect it would be